# Java counting obstacles

Tags: java, count, finch

I am making a program for a robot that will count how many times it hits an obstacle for the seconds that is running. I want to know what can I use to count the times.

For example;

if (robot.isObstacle);

start counting every time isObstacle occurs and stop when there is no obstacle.

```
Finch fRobot = new Finch();


    fRobot.setWheelVelocities(250,250);
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - before < msFinch*1000)



     if(fRobot.isObstacle() == true);{
         System.out.println(obstacleCount);
         obstacleCount++;

     }

         if(fRobot.isObstacle() == false);{
         System.out.println("No Obstacles hit");
     }
```

This doesn't seem to work I know I have done something wrong.

Comment: Little thing to clean up the code, you can use `if(fRobot.isObstable())` and `if(!fRobot.isObstacle())` to check if true or false, respectively.  Since it looks like your `Fince.isObstable()` returns a boolean, this should work for you.
Also, since your `isObstacle` can only be true or false, you can clean it up further by using an `if else`.  Also, you don't have a `{}` for your `while` loop to contain the `if` checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `While` loop seems fishy. You probably want to start a new block there.

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - before < msFinch*1000) {
```

Your `if` syntax is wrong. Remove the `;` after the condition:

```
 if(fRobot.isObstacle() == true) {
     System.out.println(obstacleCount);
     obstacleCount++;

 }

     if(fRobot.isObstacle() == false) {
     System.out.println("No Obstacles hit");
 }
```

Comment: I did the same before don't know why I changed it. The problem now is that obstacleCount++ seems to add +1 very quick. For example my obstacleCount ++ got to 277 in 10 seconds when the robot was stuck only on one obstacle.

Comment: Either there is a problem with fRobot.isObstacle() or you don't wait until the robot has cleared the obstacle before you check again.